# Get variable value by its name stored in another variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am newbie in powershell and have some problem.

**Scenario**

In my pipeline and scripts I have defined variable `$myVar = 'someValue'`. I store its name in `$varName = 'myVar'`.

**Question**

Is it possible to get myVar value by referencing $varName? I Tried something like: `$($varName)` but it returned only `myVar`, not 'someValue'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Get-Variable -Name $varName).Value
```

Or this: (as suggested by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0))

```
Get-Variable -Name $varName -ValueOnly
```

Comment: Nice; or, more directly: `Get-Variable -Name $varName -ValueOnly`

Answer (score 0):

A bit more awkward answer.

```
$a = 'b'
$b = 1
(dir variable:).where{$_.name -eq $a}.value
1
```

Or

```
(dir variable:$a).value
```

Comment: Why not just 
`$a = 'b'`
`$b = 1`
`(dir variable:$a).value`
`1`

Comment: @DougMaurer You're right.  At first I tried `variable:$a`